# Use PHP to download a .gif from a URL

Tags: php

How?

I think I've done this with .PDFs at one time in the past, but I lost the code, and now nothing is turning up on the web about how to go to a URL, get a .gif and copy the .gif file into my directory.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

```
$gif = file_get_contents("http://path.to/gif/pic.gif");
file_put_contents("path/on/server",$gif);
```

You need to have fopen wrappers enabled for this to work.

Comment: As a side note, if the GIF is enormous (>1MB), you may want to consider doing this with `fopen` and downloading in chunks. If you don't, you could get an error that PHP is out of memory.

Comment: @matbasta, Very true but it would have to be alot bigger than 1MB. Doesn't PHP default to like 64MB ?

Comment: and very few gif are bigger than 1MB

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/copy

copy() can use use a url as the source.

Comment: Why won't copy work? You can use it with streams as of 4.3. What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry but there is no best answer. 
Every answer here has a solid basis to solve this simple task.
It depends on the developer, which is usable and which not.
If you are because of that  insulted, i can also vote it up for you, just edit your answer.

Comment: copy() is definitely superior to file_put_contents() in this context, as it should operate on a file of any with minimal memory usage.  cURL should also behave comparably if correctly configured, and may actually perform better than copy().

Answer (score 0):

if your php configuration allow you to fopen url (allow_url_fopen directive in php.ini)

`file_put_contents ($filename, file_get_contents ($url));`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).